# MySql UPDATE statement with SELECT summarizing data from table 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, TABLE A has columns *token* (primary key) and *downtime* (`INT`), TABLE B has columns *token*, *status* (`ENUM` with 3 states: `active`, `unstable`, `inactive`), *duration* (`INT`).

I want to sum *duration* from TABLE B, only for the states `unstable` and `inactive`. And after that, assign the result to column *downtime*, from TABLE A.

So, for example,

```
TABLE A
=======

token             downtime
--------------------------

bv87pxicnrtk8pw       null
v3525kq2kzihb9u       null

TABLE B
=======
token                 state       duration
------------------------------------------
v3525kq2kzihb9u      active              9
v3525kq2kzihb9u    unstable             20
v3525kq2kzihb9u    inactive             60
bv87pxicnrtk8pw    unstable             11
bv87pxicnrtk8pw      active            140
bv87pxicnrtk8pw    inactive             40

RESULT
======
token             downtime
--------------------------

bv87pxicnrtk8pw         51
v3525kq2kzihb9u         80
```

I tried

```
UPDATE A
SET downtime = (SELECT SUM(duration) FROM B WHERE state != 'active' GROUP BY token)
WHERE A.token = B.token;
```

but without success.

Newbie in SQL. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql you can use join and update something as

```
update tablea a
join(
  select 
  token,sum(duration) as duration from tableb
  where state != 'active'
  group by token
)b
on b.token = a.token
set a.downtime = b.duration
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UPDATE A a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(duration) AS s
        FROM B
        WHERE state <> 'active'
        GROUP BY token  
    ) b ON a.token = b.token
SET a.downtime = b.s
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. This may well fix the problem, but it is a good idea to add some explanation of what you changed and why this solves the problem. There are heaps of newbies here and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise. Don't forget that what may be obvious to you might not be to them...

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to use a subquery in the update is good, you just need to reorganize it:

```
UPDATE A
SET downtime = (SELECT SUM(duration) FROM B WHERE state != 'active' AND A.token = B.token);
```